# Are the -client and -server command line options ignored in java7 JRE?

Tags: java

I've installed java7 jre: java -version

> java version "1.7.0_02"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_02-b13)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)

I want to test if the -server option works in the JRE. That seems to be the default on my machine. I also want to check if both the -server and the -client options are supported. So I wrote the following program:

```
public class Info {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vm.name"));
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vm.version"));
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vm.info"));
    }
}
```

If I issue the command java -client -cp e:\temp Info from the jre7\bin installation folder the program prints:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>
> 22.0-b10
>
> mixed mode

It prints the same for -server.

Are -client and -server ignored in the java7 jre? Is there online documentation about this behavior?

P.S. I know that there is now tiered compilation.

Comment: OpenJDK 7 has code for running both client and server HotSpots at once (tiered mode), although that isn't the default yet.

Comment: Didn't know that it wasn't the default. Thanks.

Comment: Spiker This looks like to be the relevant CR (current state is accepted) - http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7116795

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is documented in the [Java command page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#options).  With the 64-bit version of Java 7, only server mode is implemented.  The `-client` option is quietly ignored.  (Note that the manual says that this may change in future versions.)